# Inner join pandas dataframes with date range columns

Tags: python, pandas, outer-join

I have 2 data frames with dateranges

```
>>>>df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
          'from_dt':[pd.to_datetime('2004-01-01 00:00:00'),
                     pd.to_datetime('2005-01-01 00:00:00'),
                     pd.to_datetime('2007-01-01 00:00:00'),
                     pd.to_datetime('2011-01-01 00:00:00'),
                     pd.to_datetime('2004-01-01 00:00:00'),
                     pd.to_datetime('2012-01-01 00:00:00'),
                     pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
                     ],
         'thru_dt':[pd.to_datetime('2004-12-31 23:59:59'),
                    pd.to_datetime('2006-12-31 23:59:59'),
                    pd.to_datetime('2010-12-31 23:59:59'),
                    pd.to_datetime('2075-12-31 23:59:59'),
                    pd.to_datetime('2011-12-31 23:59:59'),
                    pd.to_datetime('2018-12-31 23:59:59'),
                    pd.to_datetime('2075-12-31 23:59:59'),
                    ],
        'val':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
>>>>df1
  ID    from_dt             thru_dt  val
0  a 2004-01-01 2004-12-31 23:59:59    1
1  a 2005-01-01 2006-12-31 23:59:59    2
2  a 2007-01-01 2010-12-31 23:59:59    3
3  a 2011-01-01 2075-12-31 23:59:59    4
4  b 2004-01-01 2011-12-31 23:59:59    5
5  b 2012-01-01 2018-12-31 23:59:59    6
6  b 2019-01-01 2075-12-31 23:59:59    7
```

The first one contains a map of ID to Value

```
>>>>df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['a', 'a', 'b'], 'ID2':['A1', 'A2', 'B1'],
                'from_dt':[pd.to_datetime('2003-01-01 00:00:00'),
                        pd.to_datetime('2010-01-01 00:00:00'),
                        pd.to_datetime('2005-01-01 00:00:00'),
                        ],
                'thru_dt':[pd.to_datetime('2009-12-31 23:59:59'),
                           pd.to_datetime('2075-12-31 23:59:59'),
                           pd.to_datetime('2075-12-31 23:59:59'),
                           ]
                })
>>>>df2
  ID ID2    from_dt             thru_dt
0  a  A1 2003-01-01 2009-12-31 23:59:59
1  a  A2 2010-01-01 2075-12-31 23:59:59
2  b  B1 2005-01-01 2075-12-31 23:59:59
```

The second dataframe has one ID mapped to the other.

I'd like to join them with some inner join logic so that I have a flat file dataframe which has the following output

```
>>>>df3 = some_function(df1, df2, end_date=pd.to_datetime('2020-12-31'))

>>>>df3
  ID2       Date  val
0  A1 2004-01-01    1
1  A1 2004-01-02    1
.
.
x  A1 2004-12-31    1
x  A1 2005-01-01    2
x  A1 2005-01-02    2
.
.
x  A1 2009-12-31    3
x  A2 2010-01-01    3
.
.
x  A2 2020-12-31    4
x  B1 2005-01-01    5
.
.
x  B1 2020-12-31    7
```

I'm sure I can loop over and do this in some inefficient manner. I'd love to learn about any existing tools and lib that can handle such tasks.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the logic here?

Comment: I'd like to know  to best way to get df3 from df1, df2

Comment: I understood that, but the logic of the transformation. So what happend to `2003-01-01` from df2?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I thought it was 2004, let me edit the question quickly

Comment: maybe try : `df2.set_index(['ID','ID2']).stack().reset_index().set_index(0).resample('D').first().ffill()` to reindex then rejoin? you could also try cross join and merge but im not 100% with your logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use list comprehension for flatten date ranges and then filter by end datetime:

```
s1 = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index,pd.date_range(r.from_dt, r.thru_dt)) 
                     for r in df1.itertuples()])
df11 = df1.drop(['from_dt','thru_dt'], 1).join(pd.DataFrame({'Date':s1.index}, index=s1))
df11 = df11[df11['Date'].lt('2020-12-31')]
print (df11)

s2 = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index,pd.date_range(r.from_dt, r.thru_dt)) 
                     for r in df2.itertuples()])
df22 = df2.drop(['from_dt','thru_dt'], 1).join(pd.DataFrame({'Date':s2.index}, index=s2))
df22 = df22[df22['Date'].lt('2020-12-31')]
print (df22)
```