# Python: Split Start and End Date into All Days Between Start and End Date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, data-science

I've got data called 'Planned Leave' which includes 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'User ID' and 'Leave Type'.

I want to be able to create a new data-frame which shows all days between Start and End Date, per 'User ID'.

So far, I've only been able to create a date_list which supplies a range of dates between start and end date, but I cannot find a way to include this for each 'User ID' and 'Leave Type'.

Here is my current function:

```
def datesplit(data):
    x = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date'])
    for i in plannedleave.iterrows():
        start = data['Start Date'][i]
        end = data['End Date'][i]
        date_list = [start + dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in range((end-start).days)]
    x.append(date_list)
    return x

>>> datesplit(plannedleave)
>>> Value Error: Can only Tuple-index with a MultiIndex
```

Here's what the data looks like:

```
>>> plannedleave.dtypes
>>>
    Employee ID                      int64
    First Name                      object
    Last Name                       object
    Leave Type                      object
    Start Date              datetime64[ns]
    End Date                datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

I'd be forever grateful if you could find a solution here! :-)

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Sure what other information would be needed?

Comment: You can check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, *Date* column alone is not enough. Your output DataFrame
should also contain at least *Employee ID*, to know which person is on
leave at the given date.

To do your task, define the following function:

```
def datesplit(data):
    parts = []
    for idx, row in data.iterrows():
        parts.append(pd.DataFrame(row['Employee ID'], columns=['Employee ID'],
            index=pd.date_range(start=row['Start Date'], end=row['End Date'],
                name='Date')))
    return pd.concat(parts).reset_index()
```

This function:

- For each source row collects "partial DataFrames", for now:

  - the only column is the *Employee ID*,
  - the index is the date range between start and end date,
  - the given *Employee ID* (a **single** value) is actually
    broadcast for all rows (each day the current employee in on leave).
- After the loop, concatenates them and converts the index (*Date*)
  into a "regular" column.

Then call it:

```
result = datesplit(plannedleave)
```

To test my code,  I used as a source DataFrame (*plannedleave*):

```
   Employee ID First Name Last Name Leave Type Start Date   End Date
0         1001       John     Brown       Xxxx 2020-05-10 2020-05-15
1         1002      Betty     Smith       Yyyy 2020-05-18 2020-05-22
```

The result, for the above data, is:

```
         Date  Employee ID
0  2020-05-10         1001
1  2020-05-11         1001
2  2020-05-12         1001
3  2020-05-13         1001
4  2020-05-14         1001
5  2020-05-15         1001
6  2020-05-18         1002
7  2020-05-19         1002
8  2020-05-20         1002
9  2020-05-21         1002
10 2020-05-22         1002
```

Comment: Do you think is fair use your sample data for my solution?

Comment: No problem, use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are necessary loops, so I prefer [`DataFrame.itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) more like [`DataFrame.iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) for [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316) in list comprehension:

```
def datesplit(df):
    df1 = df.rename(columns={'Start Date':'sdate','End Date':'edate', 'Employee ID':'ID'})
    return  (pd.concat([pd.Series(r.ID,pd.date_range(r.sdate, r.edate)) 
                        for r in df1.itertuples()])
               .rename_axis('Date')
               .reset_index(name='Employee ID'))

df = datesplit(plannedleave)
print (df)
         Date  Employee ID
0  2020-05-10         1001
1  2020-05-11         1001
2  2020-05-12         1001
3  2020-05-13         1001
4  2020-05-14         1001
5  2020-05-15         1001
6  2020-05-18         1002
7  2020-05-19         1002
8  2020-05-20         1002
9  2020-05-21         1002
10 2020-05-22         1002
```

---

Performance with 200 rows:

```
plannedleave = pd.concat([plannedleave] * 100, ignore_index=True)


def datesplit(df):
    df1 = df.rename(columns={'Start Date':'sdate','End Date':'edate', 'Employee ID':'ID'})
    return  (pd.concat([pd.Series(r.ID,pd.date_range(r.sdate, r.edate)) 
                        for r in df1.itertuples()])
               .rename_axis('Date')
               .reset_index(name='Employee ID'))


def datesplitvb(data):
    parts = []
    for idx, row in data.iterrows():
        parts.append(pd.DataFrame(row['Employee ID'], columns=['Employee ID'],
            index=pd.date_range(start=row['Start Date'], end=row['End Date'],
                name='Date')))
    return pd.concat(parts).reset_index()



In [152]: %timeit datesplit(plannedleave.copy())
98.2 ms ± 4.96 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [153]: %timeit datesplitvb(plannedleave.copy())
193 ms ± 30.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much Jezrael

Comment: This gives only date + one single column (Employee ID). How can I add all columns into the resulting dataframe?

Comment: @Vega - Use `.Index` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59717430/inner-join-pandas-dataframes-with-date-range-columns/59717690#59717690)